# Laravel group by date in foreach not working

Tags: php, laravel, group-by

I have the following code:

```
$getDate = $messages->groupBy(function($date) { 
    return Helper::ru_date('%d %b', strtotime($date->created_at->toDateString())); 
});
```

This give me messages group by date. I get an array:

14 february => messages items 
15 february => messages items

When I want do foreach and show date I get object of message. Why? I want see 14 february or 15.

My foreach:

```
@foreach($getDate as $date)
   {{ $date }} //I get collection of message, but not date
   @foreach($date as $message)
        //but this I need show messages of this date
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `getDate` is an array with the date in the keys and the messages in the values, you should adjust your loop head to:

```
@foreach($getDate as $date => $messages)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
@foreach($getDate as $date => $messages)
   {{ $date }} 
   @foreach($messages as $message)
        {{ $message }}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```